# Access to (HID) USB device in OS X

Tags: usb, osx-mavericks, hid

I have a "Serial to USB" device with two endpoints that streams data that I want to access.
Tried several IOKit methods found on Google including "code less" .kext but no luck.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [HID API for OSX](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/).